# How to get only the line with max score out of csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

my code:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as information:

reader = csv.reader(information, delimiter=';')
for row in reader:
    print('Highest score is: {} on {} by {}'.format(row[2], row[1], row[0]))
```

information in csv file:

```
Anton;12-05-2016;29
Douwe Bob;13-05-2016;44
Anton;11-05-2016;39
Douwe Bob;12-05-2016;55
Anton;10-05-2016;29
Douwe Bob;11-05-2016;69
```

When I run the program i'll get all lines printed without the max score. I try'd max(row[2]) but seems not to work, there must be somthing im doing wrong. Anyone that can help me out?

I only want to get the line printed with the max score row[2]

For those that start crying we're not going to make your homework stay away, i just want to improve my programming skills!

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_score_from_row(row):
    return float(row[-1])
max_score_row = max(csv.reader(information, delimiter=';'),key=get_score_from_row)
```

should give you the line with the max score

Comment: Thank you sir. Could you explain me what key=lambda does? I didn't study this before.

Comment: I changed it to not use lambda ... all the sort,max,min,etc functions take an optional key argument that defines a function that tells it how to sort ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I worked this. I created a new list to store the numbers and then since the row is a list itself, accessed the number element location and stored it into the new list.

```
import csv

# create a new list to store only the numbers
my_list = [] 

with open('C:\\Users\\mnickey\\Documents\\names.txt', 'r') as information:
    reader = csv.reader(information, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:

        # used to assure that the row in the reader is a list
        print(type(row)) 

        # assuming that you know where the numbers are in the file
        num = row[2] 

        # append this to the empty list
        my_list.append(num) 
print(max(my_list))
```

I hope this helps. Note that it's likely not as advanced or efficient as others might post but it should work.